# Is there a better way to iteratively code new class methods within a module in Python?

Tags: python, class

When I am coding a new class or a new method within an existing class within a module, I find myself wasting a lot of time reimporting the module and resetting class instance attributes.  An example can illustrate:

```
new_module.py
    class NewClass():
        def __init__(self, param1, param2):
            param1=param1
            param2=param2
            param3 = {}

        def meth1(self):
            do stuff
            self.param3 = new_dict

        def meth2(self):
            do stuff using self.param3
```

Let's say I'm working on meth2().  To use meth2(), I have to run this code first:

```
import new_module
instance1 = new_module.NewClass()
instance1.meth1()
instance1.meth2()
```

If meth1() takes a 2 minutes to run, I am now wasting 2 minutes every time I modify meth2() and want to test it. And I have to start a new python session to clear the namespace of the old new_module import.  Surely there is a better way?  Thanks!

Comment: You can run meth1, then serialize (`import cPickle`) the object to disk. I another program you can load the object, then run meth2. You have to add support for serialization and loading.

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do is replace the long-running task with preset data while doing the testing:

```
    def meth1(self):
        # TODO: uncomment when ready
        # do stuff
        # self.param3 = new_dict    
        self.param3 = dict(...)
```